# Controlling aspect ratio of images with % width and height of body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have these two images appearing in my site that I am pulling from another company's server. I need these photos to scale with the browser window so I've given them a % width and height to scale with the body.

The problem is some of these images are different sizes and I need all the images to look identical to each other. This is easy to do when I know the values of the image's width and height because I can just crop or resize. But how can you maintain a ratio with a scalable width and height?

I think some JavaScript is required to do this. Here's the CSS that I have:

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.image {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

Comment: Will the images be of mixed orientation or will they all be either landscape or portrait?  Typically, you would set either the width or the height to be a percentage and have the other be auto, but mixed orientation will require a class to be attached to the image identifying which it is.

Comment: They'll all be landscape. It's just the heights that fluctuate a bit so it looks off-putting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it with CSS only will take you a lot of time to optimize for all brosers.

With a few modifications and js you may achieve this using [Perfect background image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not concerned about IE8, you can just specify the `width`.  Most browsers will maintain the aspect ratio for you.